# Отобрать нужный элемент в jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Написал такой вот код:

```
<div id='avt' align='center'>
    <div id='session_true'>
        код
    </div>  
    <div id='session_false'>
        код
    </div>  
</div>
```

Вопросик, как правильно отобрать `session_false` и `session_true` в `jQuery`? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Сразу оба элемента? А разве уже не работают стандартные селекторы?

    var elems = $('#session_true, #session_false');

Comment: Мне нужно отобрать один, но у меня почему то не получается..

Comment: Дайте ссылку на страницу.

Comment: на локалке работаю.

Comment: А что в консоли, без ошибок?

Comment: Спасибо всем, я сам разобрался)

Comment: два раза одинаковый id прописал ?

Comment: Нет. Там нужно было малех по другому)

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, то следующий код скроет блок `session_true` и покажет блок `session_false`, к примеру:

```
$('#session_true').hide();
$('#session_false').show();
```

Советую начать изучение азов jQuery (но сначала javascript).

Comment: Я знаю что так отбирать, просто так не хочет работать..

Comment: Значит у вас где-то ошибка в другом месте. Смотрите в консоль.

Comment: @oOKomarOo, может у вас на странице несколько элементов с одинаковым ID?

Comment: нет, я уже это проверял..

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй везде поменять $ на jQuery...у меня на wordpress тоже ничего не срабатывало пока не поменял...

Comment: @zhekonya, In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict().

Comment: У меня в средине дива столбики <tr><td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td></tr> Когда их убираю то прячется. Что мне с этим делать, не подскажите?

Comment: Выучить азы HTML.

Comment: Очень полезная информация.

Comment: Вы будете удивлены, но это действительно очень полезная информация. Народ уже просто задолбался отвечать на вопросы в стиле "как поменять местами два элемента в массиве". Поэтому совет идти курить мануалы оказывается самым ёмким:). Ах да! А еще иногда гуглить перед тем, как задавать вопросы на форумах. Это банально экономит время.

Answer (score 0):

посмотрите метод [find](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Answer (score -1):

не скажу за блоки ДИВ, но с инпутами - были проблемы. по АЙДИ не хотели выбираться, пришлось юзать нэйм
задайте имя такое же как ИД и

> $('div[name=session_true]')..........